# Get raw file content using Stash Rest API

Tags: bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

I am able to get raw file content using the Bitbucket REST API, as

https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/AccountName/Repo_Slug/raw/master/MyFolder/MyFile.cs,

Is there a equivalent to get it from Stash using Stash Rest API. I couldn't find it here:
https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/2.0.1/stash-rest.html#resources

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just specify the file's URL and append `?raw`

`http://example.com/projects/TES/repos/testrepo/browse/testfile?raw`

As I mentioned, that is not a function of either REST API, it is just the full URL of the file.

Comment: You can get a JSON summary of file details using a URL like http://mydomain.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/TES/repos/testrepo/browse/testfile

Comment: Curious, I don't see any reference to a branch name there. Does it default to `master`? Is there a way to specify a different branch? All assuming it's a git repo, of course.

Comment: To get file from branch `feature` you need to download file from http://example.com/projects/TES/repos/testrepo/browse/testfile?raw&at=feature

Comment: Is there any way to get, the raw file using JAVA API? What I am looking is to get raw file with SSH Key authentication, which is used from GIT bash. But the SSH authentication, I suppose would not be working with REST API, so I am looking if JAVA API or GIT API could help with that. Please share some inputs or any examples

Answer (score 3):

With 1.0 of stash/bitbucket api, you could use the below to get the raw file content

```
    https://example.com/rest/api/1.0/TES/repos/testrepo/raw/testfile?at=feature/branch
```

Comment: slight correction, `https://example.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/TES/...` Missing `projects`. Ref: https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/7.7.1/bitbucket-rest.html#idp358